# Is there likely any star systems in the very middle of the largest voids?

Tags: rogue-planet, intergalactic-space

I imagine this question is as old Hubble's red shift measurements publication. Has there been enough time for any solar system to make it right to the middle of a void? Any Goldilocks scenarios there? I assume the same answer would apply to rogue planets